# Yii Booster assets with symlink

Tags: yii, assets, yii-booster

Im using YiiBooster, but I don't like that is generates folder inside the assets dir and copying a bunch of files into it. I would like it to create symlinks instead, like Yii assetManager:

```
$assetManager = Yii::app()->assetManager;
$assetManager->linkAssets = true;
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your app is configured to user linkAssets booster automatically follows this ... all what you need is to configure your app to use linkAssets, this way ...

```
'components'=>array(
'assetManager'=>array(
    'linkAssets' => true,
),
```